# Setting property value by name

Tags: delphi, properties, rtti

In a Delphi class I have some properties that I would like to set by accessing them by their name.
Now I use e.g. `Settings.AllowSysop := True;`

That I would like to do something like  `Settings('AllowSysop').Value := True;`

The reason for this is that when setting what my users can access this is read from a license file where the line read from the file (it is like an `INI` but encrypted) might look like

```
AllowSysop = True
```

I know it is some RTTI look-a-like code that has to be made but I can't quite figure it out.

I think it would make it a bit easier for me if this was possible.

Hope the explanation is making sense

Comment: All of your values are boolean?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
implementation
uses TypInfo;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   if IsPublishedProp (Button1, 'Visible') then
    begin
      SetPropValue (Button1, 'Visible',false);
    end;

end;
```